# How to create a measure to count the number of times item appears in a filtered list (power BI, DAX)

Tags: dax

[image]

Hi, I would like to create a measure in power BI to return the number of times the terminal code appears in my list. The list is filtered from a slicer when I select the service code.

Thanks for any help! been stuck at this seemingly simple problem for a few days!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count occurence in selected filter context then use ALLSELECTED:

```
CountOfCode = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(Sheet1), filter(ALLSELECTED(Sheet1), Sheet1[Terminal Code ] = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Terminal Code ]) ))
```

[image: without filter]

[image: with filter]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! this works!! finally solved this problem that i have been trying to solve for days!

Comment: mark it as answered